# Why can response.content be read twice and can't be decoded to json

Tags: python, json, python-requests, decoding

I found a strange behavior today.
I sent a message in google cloud messaging via the python requests lib.
Then I tried to decode the response to json like this:

```
response = requests.post(Message_Broker.host, data=json.dumps(payload), headers=headers)
response_results = json.loads(response.content)["results"]
```

This crashed with a decode error:

```
response_results = json.loads(response.content)["results"]
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/simplejson/__init__.py", line 505, in loads
    return _default_decoder.decode(s)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/simplejson/decoder.py", line 370, in decode
    obj, end = self.raw_decode(s)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/simplejson/decoder.py", line 400, in raw_decode
    return self.scan_once(s, idx=_w(s, idx).end())
JSONDecodeError: Expecting value: line 1 column 1 (char 0)
```

This happened on my productive system, so I added some debug logging to get to know what the actual content of the response is like this:

```
        logger.info("GCM-Response: " + str(response))
        logger.info("GCM-Response: " + response.content)
        logger.info("GCM-Response: " + str(response.headers))
```

Now the actual weird behavior occured. It got logged correctly and didn't throw the decoding error anymore.

Can someone explain me that behavior?

I have also checked what response.content actually is:

```
@property
    def content(self):
        """Content of the response, in bytes."""

        if self._content is False:
            # Read the contents.
            try:
                if self._content_consumed:
                    raise RuntimeError(
                        'The content for this response was already consumed')

                if self.status_code == 0:
                    self._content = None
                else:
                    self._content = bytes().join(self.iter_content(CONTENT_CHUNK_SIZE)) or bytes()

            except AttributeError:
                self._content = None

        self._content_consumed = True
        # don't need to release the connection; that's been handled by urllib3
        # since we exhausted the data.
        return self._content
```

It is part of the `requests` models. Not a actual property but made accessable via the `@property` decorator.
For my understanding, the first time the content is read for the logging, the `_content_consumed` flag is set to True. Therefore the second time, when I read it for the json decoding it should actually raise the Runtime Error.

Is there an explanation, which I just not found when browsing the requests docs?

Comment: Does response.json() give you the required json ?

Comment: I haven't tried this yet, but I'm wondering about the behavior I asked about.

Comment: The correct way to read json data using Requests is `response.json()`. Try that first in place of your `json.loads` and see if it resolves your problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Therefore the second time, when I read it for the json decoding it should actually raise the Runtime Error.

No, it won't raise a `RuntimeError`. When you access `response.content` first time it will cache actual data into `self._content`. On the second (third, fourth, etc) access `if self._content is False:` is falsy, so you will get content cached in `self._content`.

The `if self._content_consumed:` check is most likely internal assert to discover attempts to read data from the socket multiple times (which is obviously an error).

---

It can't be decoded to JSON, because you received not a JSON in response body or received empty body. Maybe it is 500 response or 429. It's impossible to say without seeing actual response.